# "$or needs an array" on a request where $or is an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I try to implement a `$or` query in mongodb but got the error: `$or needs an array`.

Here is my request:

```
const filters = {
  "$or": [
    {
      "positionStatus": {
        "$in": [
          "trainee"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "positionStatus": {
        "$exists": false
      }
    },
    {
      "positionStatus": []
    },
    {
      "positionStatus": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tested the type of the `$or` attribute of my object with `Array.isArray` and it returns `true`:

```
console.log('is array: ', Array.isArray(filters['$or']));
```

I use the version 2.2.33 of the Nodejs driver and Mongorito.

```
const items = yield Item
  .sort(formatted_sort)
  .find(filters)
  .map(item => ...);
```

### Edit

After investigating a bit more, it appears the problem is when using the expression with `count`:

```
const count = yield Sentence
  .where(filters).count();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please also show how exactly you're executing that query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using mongorito to execute the request. I updated my question with the code...

Comment: Updated my answer. The problem is when using `count`...